# Eclipse: Invoke method of inaccessible Java object

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Suppose the following code:

```
package demo;

public class DebugMe {
    static Enigma e = new Enigma();
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        e.toString(); // breakpoint here
    }
}

class Enigma {
    private Secret secret = new Secret();
}

class Secret {
    private void callme() {
        System.out.println("Yay!");
    }
}
```

When debugging with Eclipse, is it somehow possible to invoke `DebugMe.e.secret.callme()` from the debugger (without previously stepping into any method of an `Enigma` object)?

I can't do it, because I can't get hold of a reference to `secret`, I can only look at it yearningly in the variables or expressions view.

I can't use detail formatters for it and I would really, really like not to use reflection.

Comment: In IntelliJ, you can just run "Evaluate expression" in the debugger and type in exactly `DebugMe.e.secret.callme()`.  I would hope Eclipse offers the same functionality :)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth It does. In the 'Debug' perspective, the 'Expressions' view.

Comment: »The field Enigma.secret is not visible«

Comment: That doesn't affect IntelliJ.  Again, can't comment on the Eclipse status-quo.

Comment: To be sure I understand: you want to break encapsulation and access a private member of an object you have a reference to? If that's the case, reflection is the only option that Java offers. I don't know why the debugger would be able to bypass this fundamental concept of the language other than by the provided mechanism.

Comment: @E-Riz - Imagine that's how a debugger does all variable/expression watches, etc.